# How can I ensure that Column_A can only have a value if Column_B is NULL? And vice versa

Tags: sql, postgresql, constraints, check-constraints

I'm attempting to create a table that has three columns:

`id`

`paid_at`

`failed_at`

How can I make sure that `paid_at` can only have a value if `failed_at` is `NULL`?

Here is my current code:

```sql
 CREATE TABLE charges(
      id        TEXT     NOT NULL     PRIMARY KEY,
      paid_at   TEXT,
      failed_at TEXT
    );

    ALTER TABLE charges
      ADD CONSTRAINT paid_at CHECK (failed_at IS NULL);

    ALTER TABLE charges
      ADD CONSTRAINT failed_at CHECK (paid_at IS NULL);
```

I also want to make sure that BOTH cannot be null.

How can I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following predicate:

```
alter table charges add constraint exclusive_rule check (
  paid_at is null and failed_at is not null or
  paid_at is not null and failed_at is null
);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `num_nonnulls()` in the check constraint:

```sql
alter table charges 
  add constraint only_one_not_null 
  check (num_nonnulls(paid_at, failed_at) = 1);
```

That ensure that exactly one of the columns is not null and the other is null.

If you consider a string with only spaces to be "null" as well, you could extend that to:

```sql
alter table charges 
  add constraint only_one_not_null 
  check (num_nonnulls(nullif(trim(paid_at),''), nullif(trim(failed_at),'')) = 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

I am inclined to do this with addition.  To check that one of a group of columns is not null, count the number of not-null values:

```
check ( (paid_at is not null)::int + (failed_at is not null)::int) > 0 )
```